# Does light fixture need grounded to crossbar and metal box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I'm doing new work installation of light fixture that has a metal box.  I have a 14/2 w/ ground cable coming into the box.  I have run a pigtail to the ground screw on the box and connected that to the ground from the light fixture and ground from the 14/2.  Do I also need to wire the ground screw on the crossbar bracket to ground or is the crossbar bracket assembly being screwed to the metal box considered sufficient bonding?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure, AIUI, code requires that the ground _from the cable_ be directly connected to the ground screw on the metal box. Then, all other grounds connect to the box. Is this what you've done? I'm not certain...

Comment: @FreeMan ground from cable is wire nutted to pigtail to box and ground from fixture.

Comment: While that will do the job, I'm not certain it's 100% to code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cross bar bracket will be grounded when you screw it to the metal junction box. If your junction box was plastic, then you'd want to ground the bracket by connecting your ground wire to it